# Which os.Signal triggered cancel() when using NotifyContext()?

Tags: go, operating-system, signals

[signal.NotifyContext()](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext) was introduced in go1.16.

With [signal.Notify()](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#Notify) you can get [os.Signal](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Signal) which got caught.

How to get [os.Signal](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Signal) which triggered context cancellation when using [signal.NotifyContext()](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext)?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(ch,
        os.Interrupt,    // SIGINT, Ctrl+C
        syscall.SIGTERM, // systemd
    )
    call := <-ch

    log.Printf("system call: %s", call)
    // system call: interrupt
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(
        context.Background(),
        os.Interrupt,    // SIGINT, Ctrl+C
        syscall.SIGTERM, // systemd
    )
    defer stop()

    <-ctx.Done()

    log.Printf("system call: %s", ctx.Err())
    // system call: context canceled
    // I want the specific signal like with Notify()
}
```

Comment: [`NotifyContext`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/os/signal/signal.go;l=277;bpv=1;bpt=1) is a very simple convenience function; all it does is `cancel` the context when a notification is received; info on the signal that triggered this is thrown away (so is not available). See [this comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37255#issuecomment-621357594) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the triggering signal information when using `signal.NotifyContext`.

However, Looking at [the source](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19:src/os/signal/signal.go;l=277) it's fairly trivial to adapt this to your needs:

```
type signalCtx struct {
    context.Context

    cancel  context.CancelFunc
    signals []os.Signal
    ch      chan os.Signal
    Fired   os.Signal // <- add this
}
```

and in the monitoring goroutine of `NotifyContext`:

```
select {
    case fired := <-c.ch:
        c.Fired = fired // <- add this
        c.cancel()
    case <-c.Done():
}
```

then to extract the `os.Signal` from your context after the fact:

```
log.Printf("signal: %v", ctx.(*signalCtx).Fired)
```

Full source: https://go.dev/play/p/UnIcFh3A6OV